Typescript docstring not generating proper documentation
I have below typescript docstring:
@param { Required<Pick<Model1, 'startTime' | 'endTime' | 'xyz'>> & Partial<Model1> } body specification

I run npm run documentation to generate HTML based documentation. I am expecting documentation with body param like:
body(Required<Pick<Model1, 'startTime' | 'endTime' | 'xyz'>> & Partial<Model1>) specification

but I can see:
body(any)
I can see there is issue with '&' but not able to get rid of it. What is right way to use both Required & Partial in docstring
